# GWT can you controle the volume of a frame

Tags: java, audio, gwt, streaming

in my application i have a frame with an url:

```
private Frame monstercatPlayer;
monstercatPlayer = new Frame("");
monstercatPlayer.setVisible(false);
panel.add(monstercatPlayer);
```

On a button click i give this frame an url:

```
playMonstercatStream.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            GWT.log("clicked Image url: " + monstercatPlayer.getUrl());
            if (monstercatPlayer.getUrl().equals("https://player.twitch.tv/?volume=0.13&!muted&channel=monstercat")) {
                    monstercatPlayer.setUrl("");
                } else {
                    monstercatPlayer.setUrl("https://player.twitch.tv/?volume=0.13&!muted&channel=monstercat");
                }
            }
      });
```

Is there a way how I can control the volume of the the IFrame...maybe over HTMl/DOM?...I know i can manipulate the url then the frame reloads and that takes some time.

Or is there a better way to implement audio only from twitch stream in GWT?

Thanks for any suggestion, tipps or help

Comment: Maybe check out the API's provided by twitch ?
https://dev.twitch.tv/

If something for javascript is available it is possible to use it from GWT.

Comment: @Knarf I looked through the docs of the twitch API but I didn't found what I was asking for. My question were if I can control the volume of the frame and not how to control the volume of the twitch player - maybe in future I have an other video or stream which is not from twitch

Comment: @KilledByCheese I'm not familiar with embedding twitch videos, but it would be nice if you can use html5 `<video>` element to show videos. It offers a lot of features like setting volume. I know if you want to embed youtube videos into `<video>`, you can append "&html5=True" to your video url to make it show up in `<video>`.